# xcb - cannot find xcb_map_window in sources

Tags: x11, window-managers, xcb

I just went [on the xcb download page](http://xcb.freedesktop.org/dist/) and downloaded the different archives (the most recent ones) but had no luck finding the implementation of `xcb_map_window` with grep. I've merely found its prototype though.

Since it has the `xcb` prefix, I thought it would be there.

What is the catch? Where is it?

Comment: Have you tried compiling the code? Doesn't it `autogen` some parts?

Comment: I didn't try that I needed to see the source code to understand how it worked :(